# Values from database using jdbc showing null values

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am a beginner in JDBC .
I have written the following code 
I have checked the table the values are not inserting properly?I don't know where i am wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

class Emp
{
    int eno,sal;
    String name,dept;
    Connection cn=null;
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    Emp()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter Employee number:");
            eno=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Enter salary:");
            sal=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


            System.out.println("Enter name:");
            name=(br.readLine());


            System.out.println("Enter Department:");
            dept=(br.readLine());

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee","root","");
            if(cn==null)
                System.out.println(" error in connection");
            st=cn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("insert into emp values(eno,sal,name,dept);");
            System.out.println("Record Inserted");

            rs=st.executeQuery("select * from emp");
            rs.first();

            System.out.println("Employee table");

            while(!rs.isLast())
            {
            System.out.println("Eno:"+rs.getInt(1)+"sal:"+rs.getInt(2)+"name:"+rs.getString(3)+"dept:"+rs.getString(4));
            rs.next();
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Emp e=new Emp();
    }
}
```

The Problem is that 
the output is showing like this

```
Eno:0sal:0name:dept:
Eno:0sal:0name:dept:
Eno:0sal:0name:dept:
Eno:0sal:0name:dept:
Eno:0sal:0name:dept:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually passing in the variables into your SQL INSERT `String` so there's a high probability that an exception is being thrown but not reported in the empty exception block. In that case, the table will be empty, producing null values on any `executeQuery`

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into emp values(" + eno "," + sal + ",'" + name + "','" + dept + "');");
```

Also don't let a possible `SQLException` occur silently, add

```
catch (SQLException sqle) {
   sqle.printStackTrace();
}
```

Better to use a `PreparedStatement` to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: i hv tried this st.executeUpdate("insert into emp values("+eno+","+sal+","+name+","+dept+");"); but still not showing values

Comment: @Amol you need single quotes for the last 2 params as they are text types, see update